# how to pass textbox value in asp.net to a code on update click

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an issue with the following code, the markup is as follows:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView" runat="server" 
            AutoGenerateEditButton="True" 
            OnRowDataBound="GridView_RowDataBound" 
            OnRowEditing="GridView_RowEditing" 
            OnRowUpdating="GridView_RowUpdating"
            CssClass="gridv">

            <Columns>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ASN"> 
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblASN" runat="server" Text='<% #Eval("ASN")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtASN" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ASN")%>' CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
...
```

However when I run this code to get the new changed values from the textboxes that were successfully generated and populated, I only get the initial values not the news that user has entered, the code behind this is:

```
Protected Sub GridView_RowUpdating(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles GridView.RowUpdating
    Try
        Dim row As GridViewRow = GridView.Rows(e.RowIndex)
        Dim ID As Integer = DirectCast(row.FindControl("txtID"), TextBox).Text

        Dim sASN As String = DirectCast(row.FindControl("txtASN"), TextBox).Text
        Dim sDescription As String = DirectCast(row.FindControl("txtDescription"), TextBox).Text
        Dim sManufacturer As String = DirectCast(row.FindControl("ddlmanufacturer"), DropDownList).SelectedValue

        GridView.EditIndex = -1
    Catch
    End Try
    ShowEmpDetails()
End Sub
```

So when I click the update button I use a message box to write the variables above and the values that I get are the same ones that got initially written to the textboxes, not the text that the user has changed?
I have worked out this code from a similar example in which this works with no issues, I honestly can not figure out what I am doing wrong?

As requested Page_Load event is calling this function:

```
Private Sub ShowEmpDetails()
    Dim query As String = "SELECT * from inventory.all_items"
    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(query)
    cmd.Connection = myConn
    Dim sda As New MySqlDataAdapter
    sda.SelectCommand = cmd
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    sda.Fill(dt)
    GridView.DataSource = dt
    GridView.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please share your Page_Load event handler implementation?

Comment: Does the grid have an `AutoPostback` property by chance? are you using any `Ajax` Controls?

Comment: @David Espino, no none of that is used.

Comment: The fact that you have your `RowUpdating` handler wrapped in a try / catch block is worrying me.  Why did you add that?  Nothing in there should *need* that.  Does it give you an error without it?  If so, that's your problem.

Comment: @Bradly, yes you were right I am getting an error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' when I run it, I did not noticed it previously because of that try statement, the error is on all 'DirectCast' lines, however I do not understand why it can not find those textboxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok... there are so many things wrong with your coding approach that I don't know where to begin. Sorry.

Lets' start again and I'll explain how to properly pass values between the DOM and your code-behind.

Firstly, you need to understand how the `DOM` populates and builds the `HTML` for the browser to know what's going on.

I would test your project in `Firefox` and use the `Inspector` tool (right-click wep page). That tool is gold and has saved my already bald-head from revealing my skull!! :-)

As you know, the GridView control binds both the "view" and "edit" portions of the control into the same code. I can see you have `Eval()` for the view portion of the control (or the mode of the control I should say) and you have `Bind()` for the Edit mode. That is good. I personally hate `BoundControls,` as you cannot really see what's going on under the hood.

Next, **avoid** using `AutoPostBack` like the plaque! It's just ugly.

Get familiar with `AjaxControlToolKit` (there are others too, but start with the Ajax), and the `ASP:UpdatePanel`.

So in your case something like this ...

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upADDMAIN" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
       <asp:GridView ID="GridView" runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateEditButton="True" 
        OnRowDataBound="GridView_RowDataBound" 
        OnRowEditing="GridView_RowEditing" 
        OnRowUpdating="GridView_RowUpdating"
        CssClass="gridv">
```

Try and put as much functionality back into the defaults of the `GridView` control. So go back to your DESIGNER mode in VStudio and add all the functionality you need like EDIT, UPDATE, DELETE, etc in the design mode of the `GridView.` This will also make sure your `SQLDataSource` is updated at the same time with the right SQL for the task.

Now why are you using `OnRowEditing` and `OnRowUpdating`?

My rule-of-thumb is always to keep things to a minimum and give as much control to ASP.net as possible. This avoids re-inventing the wheel with code-behind stuff that ASP.net can handle straight out of the box.

I generally use `OnDataBound(), OnRowDataBound(), and OnRowUpdating()` to both read the data and pre-UPDATE the data before the Update() gets called by the controls.

ie:

```
protected void gvLogins_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)e.Row;
    {
        if (gvRow.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
```

and

```
protected void gvLogins_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    //apply values to the SQL parameters for UPDATE, etc
    GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)gvLogins.Rows[e.RowIndex];
```

to do some pre-Update updates outside of the GridView for example.

I never do prerendering or preloading of data in the `PageLoad()`. That is just re-inventing the wheel, when by default most ASP.net controls already have connectivity and updating built in!

Oh and to get the values of controls inside a GridView... just use FindControl() **but in the right place**! ie: the DataBound() events etc.

```
            DropDownList ddlAgent = (DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("ddlAgent");
            HiddenField hfAgentID = (HiddenField)gvRow.FindControl("hfAgentID");  //from overall state,as EDIT mode defaults the hfAgentID to 0!
            if (ddlAgent != null && hfAgentID != null)
                ddlAgent.SelectedValue = hfAgentID.Value;
```

Sorry I only use C#, not VB.

Good luck.